# IBM Worklight 6.1 - White screen while reloading the app

Tags: dojo, ibm-mobilefirst, blackberry-10

I have developed a Worklight application in Dojo for BlackBerry OS 10.

When I click the "Reload" button, the `WL.Client.reloadApp()` API method is invoked.
The app gets reloaded with white screen.

I have attached the screenshots which will explain the issue.

[image: Homescreen]

[image: when reloading]

[image]

Comment: If I understand, you want to reload content only?

Comment: I want to reload the application.

Comment: Are you seeing the same behavior in Worklight's Mobile Browser Simulator as in the BB10 simulator or Ripple? Can you post the code snippet? I have been unable to reproduce this issue in the Mobile Browser Simulator.

Comment: @nspeete Actually only in blackberry 10 simulator this problem occurs not in mobile browser simulator and I have added the code also in the question

Comment: No, you did not add code to the question...

Comment: @IdanAdar, this is the code used to reload the App onclick of the button WL.Client.reloadApp();

Comment: Funny, you are... anyway, writing an answer now.

Comment: @dhineshsundar, see my answer below. Can this question be resolved?

Answer (score 2):

IMO this is the expected behavior.

When using `WL.Client.reloadApp()` you essentially request to reload the web resources of the application; you can't expect to both show them and reload them at the same time. Thus, this is the expected behavior and the same will also happen when previewing via Worklight Console's MBS (I've checked that).

A question to ask is, why would you want to have such a button in your application to reload the app... Your scenario is unclear to me.

What you can do perhaps, is display some image while reloading using the [Cordova Splashscreen API](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/cordova_splashscreen_splashscreen.md.html). Something like this:

```
function reload() {
    navigator.splashscreen.show();
    WL.Client.reloadApp();
}
```

This way when executing this function a splash will be displayed, masking the "white screen".
Next, after the app inits, you'll need to remove the splash...

So in `wlCommonInit()` you'll do:

```
function wlCommonInit() {
    navigator.splashscreen.hide();
    ...
    ...
}
```

This should not interfere with the splash image shown by the Worklight framework upon application startup.

Try it.